# How to select columns from more then thee tables using dplyr&

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I develop a Shiny app using reactivity programming assuming that reactive objects are functions thus in order to refer to some table I have to pass `()` after table we are refering to.

An algorithm I've worked out is well realised using `SQL` syntax (in this case  `sqldf` package). I provide you with one query as an example:

```
ratios_135_final <- sqldf("select  
                  b.tot_cap_after_stress*100/c.rwa_0_after_stress as \"n1.0_after_stress\", 
                  b.osn_cap_after_stress*100/c.rwa_2_after_stress as \"n1.2_after_stress\",
                  b.bas_cap_after_stress*100/c.rwa_1_after_stress as \"n1.1_after_stress\",
                  a.\"REGN\", d.\"NAME\", a.date, f.buff 
                  from ratios a 
                  inner join capital_final b on (a.\"REGN\" = b.\"REGN\")
                  inner join rwa_final c on (a.\"REGN\" = c.\"REGN\") 
                  inner join names d on (a.\"REGN\" = d.\"REGN\")
                  inner join buffer_bank  f on (a.\"REGN\" = f.\"REGN\")  ")
```

As you can see there are 5 tables that I'm refering to build a query. But I can't write for instanse `...*from ratios()*`. I tried to learn dplyr syntax but I've revealed that `dplyr` does not provide any functions for working with three or more tables.

Could you help me you to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming `ratios` is a function that returns a data frame `DF <- ratios(); sqldf("... from DF ...")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the equivalent code however this assumes that "REGN" is the only column that exists in multiple tables. If there are other columns names that are shared among different tables  it will need further modifications.

```
ratios_135_final <-
  ratios %>%
  inner_join(capital_final, by = "REGN") %>%
  inner_join(rwa_final, by = "REGN") %>%
  inner_join(names, by = "REGN") %>%
  inner_join(buffer_bank, by "REGN") %>%
  mutate(n1.0_after_stress = tot_cap_after_stress * 100 / rwa_0_after_stress,
         n1.2_after_stress = osn_cap_after_stress * 100 / rwa_2_after_stress,
         n1.1_after_stress = bas_cap_after_stress * 100 / rwa_1_after_stress) %>%
  select(n1.0_after_stress, n1.2_after_stress, n1.1_after_stress, REGN.x, NAME, date, buff) %>%
  rename(REGN = REGN.x)
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain more deeply what does REGN.x mean?

Comment: Basically when you join using dplyr the name of the column remains the same, however if the column exist in multiple tables then columns with similar names get concatenated with .x for first table and .y for second table.

Comment: Could you explain me how to compose a query from two tables without joining? Assume I have two tables, each of them contains only 1 row and no one column to be joined?

Comment: You can use cbind() function to do this however the number of rows has to be equal to each other.

Comment: you know I had been mistaken, there are several rows in first table and one row in second table. I need to compose query without joining tables.

Comment: If so you can use merge(df1, df2)